# Why have stock portfolios in My Yahoo stopped working?

Tags: yahoo

I have several stock portfolios in the "My Yahoo" stock portfolio widget.

It seems that since Jan. 1, they have stopped working - now every value is simply "N/A".

I have tried this on three different computers (two at home, one at work) and with every browser available.  I've tried clearing all my cookies, disabling all my plug-ins, and nothing seemed to make a difference.

Is this something specific to my Yahoo account, or is this a known problem?

Comment: At least one other person has complained of the [same issue](http://malaysia.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120104051049AAd4Eiv) on a Malaysian Yahoo Answers page. However, the stock portfolio in My Yahoo seems to be working fine for me - I'm seeing information for all of the stocks & indices that I'm following.